# Redirect Loop on $_GET Request

Tags: php

I have a bit of an issue, I'm getting a redirect loop and I've changed absolutely nothing for it to start. I haven't edited a single line of code to make it stop, and I've done extensive debugging and can't find the issue.

Whenever I put a zip code in that search box, it just gives me an infinite redirect loop.

My site is sparkle wash . com (can't post more than two links in a post, sorry!)

My index.php file: http://pastebin.com/8NuUt6Lu

My search.php http://pastebin.com/cHjhAFwH

I do apologize if it seems like a stupid mistake, but I'm new to PHP and I didn't even write this. I'm just these people's web designer and they expect me to fix what they had someone write for them a year ago.

**Edit** Here is what my .htaccess looks like http://pastebin.com/4YR6SqMh, I have no idea what it should look like/do.

Comment: Is not your fault.. but the way the programmer has coded those files is "really really good".. :|

Comment: Instead of copying the complete pages try to include just the lines of code which generate the problem.

Comment: There are lines in the `index.php` code which redirect to `/searchresult/...`, so I guess that might be going to `search.php`?  You'd have to find out, I suppose.  But then there's nothing in `search.php` which performs any redirect at all.  So it seems that you're just going to have to debug this some more.

Comment: Try placing a `die()` or `exit()` after each of header assignments in the index.php

Comment: Remove all but one of the redirects from the index and see what happens. Also check your header.php and see if there are any other redirects in here. As @David says search does not have any redirects and I would suspect as you redirect to `searchresult?state=` if there were any other redirects in header or functions this would create the loop. I have tested the current code and it seems to function as expected.

Comment: To me it appears the problem occurs when the redirect location has a question mark ( such as `55001` ) - the ones that do not such as `20331` resolve ok so I would guess the htaccess file needs some tweaking

Comment: Would it be a security concern if I were to show you what's in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the location items with something like this, its easier to read and update:

```
if(!empty($state = $_GET["state"])){

    // Location data add multiple lines
    $locations["/placercounty"] = array(
        "ranges" => array(
            array("from" => 90001, "to" => 96162)
        )
        "matches" => array(
            "california",
            "placer-county",
            "auburn",
        )
    );
    $locations["/northcentralohio"] = array(
        "ranges" => array(
            array("from" => 44312, "to" => 44312)
        )
        "matches" => array(
            "akron",
        )
    );

    // No need to touch below this
    $state = clean($state);
    $theZip = strtolower($state);
    $location = false;
    foreach($locations as $url => $matchData){
        if(isset($matchData["matches"])){
            if(in_array($theZip, $matchData["matches"])){
                $location = $url;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isset($matchData["ranges"])){
            foreach($matchData["ranges"] as $rangeData){
                if(isset($rangeData["from"]) && isset($rangeData["to"])){
                    if($theZip >= $rangeData["from"] && $theZip <= $rangeData["to"]){
                        $location = $url;
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if($location){
        header("Location: " . $location);
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be what broke it?

Comment: The other problem could be your `.htaccess` file, are you testing locally and it does not work but it does on the site?

Comment: I've attached my .htaccess to my original post. I've never messed with any of these, so if you have any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it!